# Google maps not working inside modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have been trying to get google maps to work inside a modal but when i run it i get the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null, i have read through all the solutions on here already and i think it may be because the modal doesn't exist when the page loads so i tried using ng-init to load it when the modal loads but i still get the same error. I tried putting an alert inside the map controller and found that it was running when the main page loads rather than when the modal loads.

Controller

```
.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
  var mapProp = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapProp);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });
    $scope.map = map;
}
})
```

Modal

```
<ion-modal-view ng-controller="mapCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar id="modalheader">
        <h1 class="title"></h1>
<!-- button to close the modal -->
        <button class="button icon ion-android-close" ng-click="closeModal();"></button>
    </ion-header-bar>
<ion-content class="item-icon-right item-text-wrap" id="modal">
<ion-list id="modalitem">
<ion-item>
<!-- displays the larger view of the office address -->
    <h1>{{office.LocationName}}</h1>
        <p id="mdets">{{office.LocAddressLine1 + ", " + office.LocAddressLine2 + ", " + office.LocCity + ", " + office.LocCountryDescription + ", " + office.LocZipPostalCode}}</p>
        <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': favicon(office.id), 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !favicon(office.id)}"  ng-click="togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<!-- creates the map view from the json data -->
<div ng-init="init()">
    <div id="map" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</div>

</ion-content>

</ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: Yeah it should, i accidentally deleted it because i thought i wasn't being used, I didn't read through my code very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when

> *document.getElementById("map")*

has no **offsetWidth**, so when it's not displayed. You have to initialize the map when you want to show it, not before. So your

> *init()*

has been called when you click to open the modal.

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap the map initialization with `$timeout`.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.init();
})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for contributing. To improve your answer, please explain *why* the OP should wrap the initialization and how your solution solves the problem